# Merge two array fields in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of the following structure

```
{
   _id : ObjectId("52f0795a58c5061aa34d436a"),
   "attribute1" : [1, 3, 6, 7],
   "attribute2" : [2, 4, 6, 8]
}
```

Is there any way I can merge the two attributes while removing duplicates using aggregation query in mongoDB? I need the result to be like this:

```
{
   _id : ObjectId("52f0795a58c5061aa34d436a"),
   "attribute3" : [1, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 8]
}
```

Comment: What are duplicates here?

Comment: @heinob 6 is the duplicate here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method and the [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "attribute3": { "$setUnion": [ "$attribute1", "$attribute2" ] } 
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52f0795a58c5061aa34d436a"),
    "attribute3" : [8, 4, 2, 6, 3, 7, 1]
}
```

Comment: Nice. But if I have to join two array of objects. since set unions only with normal arrays.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify your data you can use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) with the [$each](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier once you have read the contents of one of the arrays. These would be individual updates as you cannot refer to another element of the document in an [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) operation.

If you really just want this for aggregation and can wait, then the upcoming release of MongoDB adds new [set operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation-set/) to aggregation. Particularly there is [$setUnion](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) which will do exactly what you want.

Comment: $setUnion - This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for the info. I really need to do it using the aggregation framework. I have wait for the next release though :(

Comment: Is there any work around for this in the current version using the aggregation framework?