# $project multiple fields into one field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm working with MongoDB 3.0 (we won't be upgrading until next year.) I have a requirement to get a list of unique values across multiple fields in a collection. The fields have the same value most of the time. This can be accomplished in version 3.2 by something like this:

```
db.mydata.aggregate([
  {'$project': {'combined_users': ['$user1', '$user2']}},
  {'$unwind': '$combined_users'},
  {'$group': {_id: 1, {$addToSet: '$combined_users'}}}
```

The issue is in version 3.0 we get "disallowed field type Array in..." at the combined_data.

How do I accomplish the same thing in Mongo 3.0?

Comment: In 3.2 we don't do it like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two array field in mongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21545103/merge-two-array-field-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `$setUnion` operator

```
db.mydata.aggregate([
    {'$project': { 'combined_users': { "$setUnion": ['$user1', '$user2'] }}}
])
```

Comment: I admit, I wasn't aware of $setUnion. Thank you for that. My `user1` and `user2` fields aren't arrays so I did a group on them first.

Comment: Final:
    db.mydata.aggregate([
        {$group: { _id: 1, user1: {$addToSet: "$user1"}, user2: {$addToSet: "$user2"}},
        {'$project': {'combined_users': {$setUnion: ['$user1', '$user2']}}}
    ])